# Code order influences the final result

Tags: tensorflow

I encountered a problem that the code order influences the final result. At first, the code works. After I move one line, tensorflow generates an error.

For example,

**working version:**

```
probs = net.get_output()
label_node = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, name='label_node')
top_1_op = tf.nn.in_top_k(probs, label_node, 1)
top_5_op = tf.nn.in_top_k(probs, label_node, 5)
threads = image_producer.start(session=sess, coordinator=coordinator)
for (labels, images) in image_producer.batches(sess):
    top_1_result, top_5_result = sess.run([top_1_op, top_5_op],
                                    feed_dict={input_node: images, label_node: labels})
```

**Non-working version:**

```
threads = image_producer.start(session=sess, coordinator=coordinator)   # move here
probs = net.get_output()
label_node = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, name='label_node')
top_1_op = tf.nn.in_top_k(probs, label_node, 1)
top_5_op = tf.nn.in_top_k(probs, label_node, 5)
for (labels, images) in image_producer.batches(sess):
    top_1_result, top_5_result = sess.run([top_1_op, top_5_op],
                                    feed_dict={input_node: images, label_node: labels})
```

**Tensorflow generates an error**

```
"tensorflow.python.framework.errors.NotFoundError: FeedInputs: unable to find feed output label_node:0".
```

As you can see, tensorflow should be able to find "label_node:0". Actually, tensorflow cannot find `top_1_op` and `top_5_op` either.

The content of `image_producer.start` is something similar to:

```
op_A = ...
queue_runner = tf.train.QueueRunner(queue_B, [op_B] * num_concurrent)
session.run(op_A)
t = queue_runner.create_threads(session, coord=coordinator, start=True)
```

A more strange thing is that in the non-workable version, after I add two lines in `image_producer.start`, the code works again. For example, `image_producer.start` becomes

```
op_C = ...  # new
session.run(op_C)  # new
op_A = ...
queue_runner = tf.train.QueueRunner(queue_B, [op_B] * num_concurrent)
session.run(op_A)
t = queue_runner.create_threads(session, coord=coordinator, start=True)
```

Does anyone have an idea about possible causes of this problem? Or any idea about how to debug this?

Comment: Which version of TensorFlow are you running?

Comment: I use the tensorflow pre-installed in a cluster. How can I know the version?

Comment: The easiest way is to run the command `python -c 'import tensorflow as tf; print tf.__version__'`.

Comment: The version is 0.9.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you are suffering from a [bug](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/2957) that was fixed after TensorFlow 0.9.0 was released. In that version (and earlier) TensorFlow suffered from a race condition that could lead to unrecoverable errors if you modified the graph after queue runners (or other threads calling `sess.run()`) had started. The only workaround in version 0.9.0 is to start
the queue runners (i.e. the `image_producer` in your code) *after* the graph has been completely constructed.

Comment: Thank you. I will try to ask the admin to upgrade it to 0.10 and then check whether this problem is solved.